# How can I make a number randomize like a countdown timer in Python?

Tags: python

I'm just trying to make a simple, beginner dice project in Python. And I'm trying to step it up a bit by displaying random number kinda like a countdown timer in one line in terminal. For example like a dice in the link below but in numbers.

The link:
https://rolladie.net/

The code:

```
import random

dice = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']

throwing = True
while throwing:
    throw_dice = random.choice(dice)

    if throw_dice == '1':
        print("You landed on 1!")
    if throw_dice == '2':
        print("You landed on 2!")
    if throw_dice == '3':
        print("You landed on 3!")
    if throw_dice == '4':
        print("You landed on 4!")
    if throw_dice == '5':
        print("You landed on 5!")
    if throw_dice == '6':
        print("You landed on 6!")

    throw_again = input("Want to throw again?(y/n)\n")
    if throw_again == 'y':
        throwing = True
    else:
        quit()
```

Is it possible to do it? Thanks in advance to anyone answering my question. Sorry if my question kinda weird and hard to understand.

Comment: So you want to display random numbers like `4 3 6 1 4 3 5 1 6 2 3` for maybe 5 seconds before it tells you what you really rolled?

Comment: Building on ArcKoor's idea, you can use the `time` module wait function to have an increasing gap before each and then after x amount of times, print the actual value.  In terms of one line, you would need some fancy module, or it would be best to use something like pygame or tkinter to reprint, because the terminal doesn't clear that easily (or at all, really).

Comment: you don't need those if's. just `print(f"You landed on {thro_dice:d}!")`

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint
import time

for i in range(100):
    a=randint(1,6)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print(a,end="\r")
```

Here i have used `random.randint` function to pick random number and used `end='\r'` inside `print` function so that the line itself gets updated.

And by seeing your code, here's what you can do make it more efficient:

```
import random
import time
while 1:
    throw_dice = random.randint(1,6)
    for i in range(5):
        a=random.randint(1,6)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print(a,end="\r")

    print(f"You landed on {throw_dice}!")

    throw_again = input("Want to throw again?(y/n)\n")
    if throw_again == 'n':
        quit()
```

This code works exactly same as yours, but less line required. I have used string formatting or `f string` in the `print` function to print string as well as the variable value. You can also use `print("You landed on"+throw_dice+"!")` instead of formatting, but using formatting is a good practice

Comment: Good idea about `end='\r'`

Comment: Just cosmetically I suggest replacing `print(a, end="\r")` with `print(f"You landed on {a}!", end="\r")` So there wouldn't be a jump effect once the for loop is finished

Comment: @re-za , I have  used `print(a, end="\r")` for the propose of countdown, while used `print(f"You landed on {a}!", end="\r")` for the result of dice. There should be a difference to differentiate between them. But yeah your suggestion would solve the jump effect.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! I'm really sorry if my question make you confuse. I sometimes forget to use string formatting. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Could not understand what you meant.  But going by the link, you could do something like this

```py
import random
import time

throwing = True
while throwing:
    dice_faces = int(input('Choose no of faces of the dice '))
    
    print('Dice is rolling ...')
    
    for i in range(10):
        throw_dice = random.choice(range(1,dice_faces+1))
        print(f'{throw_dice} \r', end="")
        time.sleep(0.4)

    print(f'You landed on {throw_dice}')

    throw_again = input("Want to throw again?(y/n)\n").lower()
    throwing = True if throw_again == 'y' else False
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't write it the way you can understand it. I'm not really good with english. Btw thanks for answering my question! Really appreciate it!

Comment: ignore my comment. The above code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by a countdown timer but to display a random number you can use the random module (which you are using) to display a random number, between a range if you wish too.

```
print(random.randint(0,6))
```

This will print a random number between the range of 0 to 6. It is inclusive so 0 and 6 can be picked as well. The code uses the random module and chooses an **interger** hence the ranINT between the given range. You can also use this link to learn more about the random module: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/random-module.

Comment: I'm sorry that I write it the way you can't understand it. Thanks for the link! I'm actually still experimenting with random module. Really appreciate it!